# Extension cord from grid through GFCI outlet to off grid inverter. Does the extension cord ground need connected?

Tags: grounding, gfci

I have an off grid system: PV, charge controllers, inverters, and batteries. I want to add a 120V grid input from a GFCI outlet through an extension cord directly into the inverter AC input. However, the GFCI trips when the AC input connects. But only if the ground from the extension cord is connected. Is it necessary to have the ground of the extension cord connected??

I could see an issue where the hot could touch the case of the inverter but the case would have no path back to trip the outlet's breaker. But wouldn't the GFCI protect it?

Comment: We need more specs. What inverter, what type of GFCI? Does it also trip when the inverter is off?

Comment: The inverter is an Outback FXR3048. The GFCI is a Leviton GFTR1-W. I'm not trying to solve the GFCI trip. I just need to know if it meets code to not ground the extension cord.

Comment: Update: I solved this by adding a isolation transformer. The GFCI does not trip and everything is grounded.